# Prevent general change of content in object when change is done in a function

Tags: php

Until now, I thought that if I call a function with a class instance as argument and that in this function I change the value of an attribute without returning the object, the value of the object was changed only in the scope of that function.
After doing some testing simple code proved me wrong (hence the bug in the first place).

```php
<?php
class Test
{
    private bool $var = true;

    public function getVar(): bool
    {
        return $this->var;
    }

    public function setVar(bool $var): void
    {
        $this->var = $var;
    }
}

$test = new Test();

var_dump($test->getVar()); // bool(true)

changeVarValue($test);

var_dump($test->getVar()); // bool(false) I expected that it's true here as well

function changeVarValue(Test $test)
{
    // Changing an attribute here will affect the object outside of this function
    $test->setVar(false);
}
```

Now the question, what is the cleanest way to prevent that the changes done in the function are valid only in the function and not outside ? How is it in other languages?

Is there a better solution than the following ?

```php
$test = new Test();

$unchangedVarValue = $test->getVar(); // Or even `$unchangedTest = $test` but I'm only interested in one value

var_dump($class->getVar()); // bool(true)

changeVarValue($test);

var_dump($unchangedVarValue); // bool(true)
```

### Edit

Since asked, my specific use case is the automatic login after a registration.

1. A `User` instance is created with the form that was submitted.
2. `$insertId = $this->userService->createUser($user);` is called in `RegisterSubmitAction`.
3. In `createUser` function I hash the password and replace the `password` attribute with `setPassword($hash)`.
4. This modified object is then passed to the repository which makes the db insert.
5. Back in `RegisterSubmitAction` I want to log the user in through with the standard function `$userId = $this->authService->GetUserIdIfAllowedToLogin($user);`. Which takes the user from the db and compares the creds. The same function is used in the login submit action where we don't know the hash so `password_verify($pass, $hash)` is used. I use this function as a double check to, if somehow there was an issue with inserting the user not start a session for a non-existent user.

This is much simplified. I didn't include validation etc.
When writing this I think I found the way I want to go. I'll simply add an attribute `passwordHash` to the `User` class and perhaps rename the db column to `password_hash`.
Or how would you do it? I am very open for suggestions.

Comment: Suggested [reading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

Comment: Your assumption was wrong, and your best option would be to fully embrace the fact that objects work that way instead of trying to find a workaround.

Comment: You suggest doing “ Or even `$unchangedTest = $test`“. Note that for the reasons stated by others this will not do what you want. In merely makes $unchangedTest point to (aka reference) the same object as $test.

Comment: @berend Thank you. I find this particularly interesting 
"In PHP, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object."

Comment: @Yoshi Now that I've learned that, yes I will embrace it and look at my code a bit differently.

Comment: @AHaworth holy crap right! Now after reading you and the php.net page this makes even sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you expect that? When using an object for a function input, this is always used "call by reference", meaning that the original object is **not** cloned.

In constrast: primitive data types (like a string or an integer) are always copied when used as a function argument, unless you mark them specifically with an `&`

Comment: Please see my edit for further clarification as to why I expected that.